# Types of solutions to a partial differential operator

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

Suppose that the operator D in a constant-coefficient second-order partial differential equation $D\varphi = 0$ is reducible, meaning it can factored into two distinct first-order factors $D=P_1P_2$ where
$$P_i = \alpha_i \frac{\partial}{\partial x} + \beta_i \frac{\partial}{\partial y} + \gamma_i$$
with $\alpha_i, \beta_i, \gamma_i$ constants. Show that the general solution to $D\varphi = 0$ can be written in the form $\varphi = \phi_1 + \phi_2$ with $P_1\phi_1 = 0$ and $P_2\phi_2 = 0$.

Otherwise, show that the general solution of
$$ \frac{\partial^2\varphi}{\partial x \partial y} + 2 \frac{\partial^2 \varphi}{\partial y^2} - \frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial x} - 2 \frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial y} = 0$$ is $\varphi(x,y) = f(2x - y) + e^yg(x)$

Just not really sure where to start. The question overall is confusing me, and I'm not sure what to do or how to attempt it. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that you have that:
$$\frac{\partial^2\varphi}{\partial x \partial y} + 2 \frac{\partial^2 \varphi}{\partial y^2} - \frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial x} - 2 \frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial y} = 0$$
$$\left (\dfrac{\partial }{\partial x}+2\dfrac { \partial }{\partial y}\right)\left (\frac{\partial }{\partial y} - 1 \right) \varphi  = 0$$
$$P_1P_2 \varphi=0$$

---

Now you need to solve these two partial differential equations of first order:
$$1.  \, \left (\dfrac{\partial }{\partial x}+2\dfrac { \partial }{\partial y}\right)\varphi_1 = 0$$
$$2. \, \left (\frac{\partial }{\partial y} - 1 \right) \varphi_2  = 0$$
Then you have:
$$\varphi=\varphi_1+\varphi_2$$

Comment: Ah I see that now. I did not see that I could do that when I first looked at the problem.

Comment: You're welcome @NolanParsons

Comment: You have first orders partial equations to solve and you are done

Comment: Perfect. That makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: You should end with the solution provided in the problem. And you're very welcome. @NolanParsons

Comment: @NolanParsons I added some lines in my answer I hope it's more clear now.